# Output MySQL query with PHP array - foreach loop error "illegal offset" and "invalid argument"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

To try and make this easier to understand I've reduced down this example instead of the actual code I'm using but I know where the problem is, I'm just not sure how to use `foreach` to output the result of my MySQL query.

I have an array similar to this

```
$thetablestructure = array(
 array('tableheader' => 'header 1', 'tablevalue' => 'value1'),
 array('tableheader' => 'header 2', 'tablevalue' => 'value2'),
);
```

And I want the HTML output to be something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>header 1</th>
  <th>header 2</tth>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>value 1</td>
  <td>value 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use which errors saying illegal string offset and illegal value:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$keywords = $_REQUEST['keywords'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `model` LIKE '%$keywords%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$thetablestructure = array(
        array('tableheader' => 'Header 1', 'tablevalue' => 'value1'),
        array('tableheader' => 'Header 2', 'tablevalue' => 'value2'),
        );

echo "<table><tr>";

foreach ($thetablestructure as $thetablestructure) {
 echo "<th>".$thetablestructure[tableheader]."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo('<tr>');
 foreach ($thetablestructure as $thetablestructure) {
  echo "<td>".$row["$thetablestructure[tablevalue]."]."</td>";
 }

echo('</tr>');

}
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
```

Originally this was is the code I used, before attempting to simplify and condense it down:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Retrieve keyword for MySQL query and search database
$keywords = $_REQUEST['keywords'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `model` LIKE '%$keywords%'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Heading 1</th>
  <th>Heading 2</th>
 </tr>";

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo('<tr>');
 echo "<td>".$row["$thetablestructure[tableheader]"]."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row["value2"]."</td>";
 echo('</tr>');
}

echo "</table>";

} else {
 echo "<p>0 results for ".$keywords."
}
$conn->close();
```

Hope that makes sense and someone can help me out.

Comment: Unless used in quotes, you will need to add quotes when using `$thetablestructure[tableheader]` around `tableheader` (and other similar uses)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this, where you are calling `$thetablestructure[tableheader]` :

```
foreach ($thetablestructure as $thetablestructure) {
    echo "<th>".$thetablestructure[tableheader]."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo('<tr>');
    foreach ($thetablestructure as $thetablestructure) {
        echo "<td>".$row["$thetablestructure[tablevalue]."]."</td>";
     }
//...
}
```

To this, with `$thetablestructureItem['tableheader']` :

```
foreach ($thetablestructure as $thetablestructureItem) {
    echo "<th>".$thetablestructureItem['tableheader']."</th>"; //You've opened th tag and close a td one
}

echo "</tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo('<tr>');
    foreach ($thetablestructure as $thetablestructureItem) {
        echo "<td>".$row[$thetablestructureItem['tablevalue']]."</td>";
     }
//...
}
```

You first didn't named properly the value in the `foreach` loop. You were using the same name for the collection and each item of that collection. Even if it may have worked before, this will certainly bring confusion when working/debuging on a code that uses the same name for an item and for its collection/array.

You called the index forgotting to wrap quotes around the index name.

```
$someArray = array('foo' => 42);
//access the value at index foo :
echo $someArray['foo'];
```

By the way, your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

```
$keywords = $_REQUEST['keywords'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `model` LIKE '%$keywords%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

If the request `keyword` is

```
"lol'; DROP TABLE `users`;--"
```

The query will become :

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `model` LIKE '%lol'; DROP TABLE `users`;--";
```

I suggest you to take a look at [PHP-PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and particulary at [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have made the following mistake, the key tableheader it's a string, so you have to use "'", another thing, you used the same name of the array '$thetablestructure' inside the foreach

```
foreach ($thetablestructure as $v) {
 echo "<th>{$v['tableheader']}</td>";
}
```

The next for each you used string as variable, and other mistakes, I suggest that first you isolated in one variable like $v before you try to use.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo('<tr>');
    foreach ($thetablestructure as $t) {
      $v =$t['tablevalue'];
      echo "<td>".$row[$v]."</td>";
    }

    echo('</tr>');
  }
```

Just and observation, sometimes it's better to maintain, and at same time easy to understand, if you specifically call 'value1' and 'value2' along the code, than you use an structure like $thetablestructure to dinamically build whatever you want.